# Unable to npm upgrade with vue

Tags: windows, vue.js, npm, eslint

npm upgrade has suddenly started crashing in my Vue installations ar follows. It has been fine until this morning.

The only change I can see is I updated to the latest npm

```
npm install -g npm
```

This is what happens when I try to upgrade...

```
C:\DATA\APPS\survival>npm outdated
Package      Current  Wanted  Latest  Location                  Depended by
core-js       3.10.2  3.11.0  3.11.0  node_modules/core-js      survival
sass-loader   10.1.1  10.1.1  11.0.1  node_modules/sass-loader  survival

C:\DATA\APPS\survival>npm upgrade
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: survival@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: eslint@7.24.0
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint
npm ERR!   dev eslint@"^7.24.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer eslint@">= 1.6.0 < 7.0.0" from @vue/cli-plugin-eslint@4.5.12
npm ERR! node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-eslint
npm ERR!   dev @vue/cli-plugin-eslint@"^4.5.12" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\Steve\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Steve\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-04-23T13_03_16_295Z-debug.log
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I would give yarn a try: https://yarnpkg.com/

Comment: yo: https://docs.npmjs.com/try-the-latest-stable-version-of-npm#upgrading-on-windows

Comment: npm is fine; I can upgrade individual packages, etc. etc. - it is just the @vue/cli-plugin-eslint package that seems to be causing problems.

Comment: BTW - same issue if I revert to the previous npm version (7.9.0)

Comment: Did you tried the suggested commands in the given error ? Probably because some packages are not in the dependency range.

Comment: I'm a little concerned by "to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution" - don't want to ruin my project :-(